# How to handle / inject service interface with different implementation

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 11 with Typescript
I have developed an component C with a dependency on service S (constructor dependency). Later in time, there is another piece of requirement in which I need to display a screen 90% like C, using data from a service S2 that has 90% the same signatue with S

Lets say both service have same function signature GetName(), GetAge(), GetGender()
while only S2 has GetGroup()

I am thinking extending component C to support both S1 and S2 like

```
<div *ngIf="service?.GetGroup"> {{service?.GetGroup}} </div>
```

However I am not sure how I can / should update the DI system to allow this

[Angular 8: How to provide different service instances to multiple instances of the same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827248/angular-8-how-to-provide-different-service-instances-to-multiple-instances-of-t)
My question is quite much like this question but I would like to

- "be dependent" on an Interface where the DI system provide me the instance (of the class that implements the Interface)
- Instead of "be dependent" on the Class and the DI system provides the different instances of that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `abstract class` `A` that has the method definitions of the services, and have both services implement that abstract class (in typescript you can implement an abstract class just like an interface)

In your component `C` inject that abstract class in the constructor (unlike interfaces, abstract classes can be used as injection tokens)

```js
constructor(private service: A)
```

In the parent components of the two different uses of `C`, provide the relevant services

```js
// replace useExisting with useClass if
// the service isn't already available
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-one',
  /* . . . */
  providers: [{
    provide: A, useExisting: S
  }]
})

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-two',
  /* . . . */
  providers: [{
    provide: A, useExisting: S2
  }]
})
```

Comment: That means you have to duplicate the code of component C which is not good. How can we prevent this?